# Git create from existing remote source

Tags: git

This is probably very simple but I've just started using git.

I've installed it on my server and my PC.

The server already has a functioning website but I want to use this as the main repo and branch it to my local machine. Here's what I've done so far on the server:

```
> cd /path/to/website/
> git init
> git add .
```

And on my development machine I tried this:

```
> git init
> git pull ssh://user@server/path/to/website
```

But this gives me the error "Couldn't find remote ref head"

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple but I'm not sure how I can set this up to work with an existing folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually commit anything. On the server, try `git commit`.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! As I said, I knew it was a newbie mistake. Thanks for your prompt answer!